# jquery ui resizable does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My aim is, to make the box resizable, which does not work (neither in Firefox nor in Chrome). Making it draggable works perfectly. However, in jsfiddle this code works even for resizable (slightly modified). What is wrong here?

```
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {    
                $("#box").resizable();
                $("#box").draggable();    
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="box" style="border:1px dashed red;width:42mm;height:30mm;">Text</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Its working fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9qca3oht/)**. Check for any console errors and if you don't have any then problem might be with the compatibility of `jquery` version with `jquery-ui` version

Comment: No, its working fine on jsfiddle with the very same jquery and ui versions I use in the above example.

Comment: any console errors?? Or some other plugin, if you have used any, might be conflicting!!

Comment: no console error, no other plugins

Answer (score 0):

Resizable needs a theme, the handle is an image that needs to be provided. Try adding this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```